# Is it possible to change 2 columns at SAME TIME (in just 1 step) with if-statement in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I was working with some DataFrames on python and I had a situation where I had to change 2 columns at same time in a same if condition. I solved my problem but I didn't do it with only one if-condition.

I tried to search something about that but I only found when the if condition has 2 or more columns, and not when the condition is satisfied.

Suppose we have:

```
data.head()

    Foo
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
5     b
```

If `data['Foo'] == a`, we do `data['Foo'] = c` and `data['Bar'] = 10`, else `data['Bar'] = 0`. So, the expected output is:

```
data.head()

    Foo  Bar 
1     c   10 
2     c   10
3     b    0
4     b    0
5     b    0
```

I solved that using twice `np.where()` (So, I verified 2 conditions). Do I have to use `apply()`?

I would like something like:

```
if data['Foo'] == a:
   data['Foo'] = c
   data['Bar'] = 10
else:
   data['Bar'] = 0
```

Note it verified the condition just once. Also, that's just out of curiosity :), because I already solved my problem.

Comment: Coul you add a column `Bar` and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Close, what you need is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
arr = np.where((data['Foo'] == 'a').values[:, None], ['c', 10], ['b', 0])
print (arr)
[['c' '10']
 ['c' '10']
 ['b' '0']
 ['b' '0']
 ['b' '0']]
```

But - all values are casted to strings and also for `Foo` is set `b`. So possible use case if if set all numeric or all strings values in all columns.

```
data[['Foo','Bar']] = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=data.index)
print (data)
  Foo Bar
1   c  10
2   c  10
3   b   0
4   b   0
5   b   0
```

Close pandas only solution:

```
data = data.assign(Bar = 0)
data.loc[data['Foo'] == 'a', ['Foo', 'Bar']] = ['c', 10]
```

Comment: I guess this may be what he needs, well who know tho, we never can get his "one step" logic

Comment: Interesting @Jezrael :) Although not sure OP is clear on what kind of solution he expects, but I like this approach

Comment: That is really interesting! But, I agree with @yatu, it is not as readable as the code using two np.where(). It seems so far that the best way is to treat them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
print(df.assign(Foo=df['Foo'].replace('a', 'c'), Bar=np.where(df['Foo'] == 'a', 10, 0)))
```

Output:

```
  Foo  Bar
1   c   10
2   c   10
3   b    0
4   b    0
5   b    0
```

Comment: You didn't do at the same time the changes. You did it in 2 steps

Comment: @MatheusDouglas Now it's one.

Comment: `You didn't do at the same time the changes` could you explain why this is necessary @MatheusDouglas ?? Note that you're updating 2 columns, with different logics for their respective computation

Comment: @yatu I don't know lol, i have that same question i was ready to ask the OP too, i'm hoping this is in one step in his logic.

Comment: @yatu Haha yours is rejected as well, i also don't get why he want it in "one-step" (in his logic)

Comment: @yatu They don't have different logics, because both of them need the same condition.

Comment: @MatheusDouglas Is mine in one step?

Comment: What do you mean with `at the same time the changes`, what do you understand with at the same time? One line does not necessarily mean at the same time

Comment: @yatu I solved the problem. That is just for curiosity :)

Comment: @yatu at the same time, I mean, we don't need to verify 2 or more conditions.

Comment: @U10-Forward Your answer does still verify 2 conditions.

Comment: In my case, I just use `m = df.Foo.eq('a')` once. From this result I change the values in both columns

Comment: I would like something like ``` if data['Foo'] == a then  data['Foo'] = c   data['Bar'] = 10  else:  data['Bar'] = 0 ```

Comment: Haha okay, that is not possible using ternary if statements, you can only do 1 assignment. And 2nd there is no advantage in doing so (if it where possible) in a one liner. You'd need a regular for loop @MatheusDouglas . Just use `np.where` or something like I suggested. Also note that you **want you're code to be readable**, and what you seem tohave in mind is miles away from being something intuitive and easy to read